# Would you take any negative performance review as a sign to leave?

Tags: performance-reviews

I am curious at what point a negative performance review is essentially a dismissal. I got rated a 3 out of 6 in my latest quarterly, so I am wondering if that is a sign that I should quit my current company.

I am a developer so there are lots of opportunities elsewhere.

Comment: Was the review fair?

Comment: So you were rated average? It’s not a great review, but it’s not terrible, keep in mind that most people are actually average.

Comment: Also, did the review (or subsequent meeting) give you a clear, measurable and achievable plan for getting a higher rating next time?

Comment: Some companies use bad reviews to trim the ranks. Is that what's happening here? If that's what's happening, you should leave. If on the other hand, the feedback was constructive, that's another matter. It's ultimately your call. We don't know you or your resume. Nor do we know your company or the company culture.

Comment: Just for the record, my first review at my current job was negative but mostly fair I acted on it and only had good reviews afterwards, so, give it a try.

Comment: "3 out of 6" is nowhere near enough data for us to answer this. I've seen review ratings with 8 levels, with all except the bottom 2 indicating no problems. This question absolutely needs more data.

Answer (score 18):

Well, you may definitely choose to leave after one poor review, but then you'd never get to work on the weak areas pointed to you in the "negative" review and overcome the shortcomings pointed out. If you really want to be make yourself better, take the review points, work on them and try to make it better.

After you have done your part, if you still see your efforts and endeavors are not acknowledged / recognized, then it makes sense to look elsewhere, but just one review is too early to make a call, IMHO.

Answer (score 7):

> I am curious at what point a negative performance review is essentially a dismissal.

At the point where someone with authority to do so says "this is not good enough, you are dismissed, pack up your stuff and leave". Otherwise, it's just that, a review.

Whether you should treat it as a signal to quit on your own is opinion-based. For me there are points where I will try to improve in the face of constructive, valid criticism (although I don't like being criticized just as much as the next person) and then there are point where I will consider leaving.

Those red flags are:

- The criticism being non-constructive. With no points to improve or act upon on my own, there is no point in staying if they think I'm not good. Even if they were right, without a constructive way forward, I would *stay* not good. Pointless.
- The criticism is about something I cannot change or wasn't my decision in the first place. Again, without the ability to improve on this, it's pointless.
- The criticism is based on trivially wrong data. I was once told I had not participated in the launch of our flagship product, when in fact I had worked for two weeks before release day from the minute the security guard opened the office to the minute they shoved me out the door in the evenings to lock up. Even by liberal interpretation of our labor laws, that was highly illegal in favor of the company and I wasn't even *paid* for overtime. I volunteered and never complained. But obviously, my boss had not conveyed that to their superiors (because he didn't like me) and the superiors were too incompetent to check for themselves (we had a time clock) before passing judgement. I don't like working for people who are incompetent. Why would I work for clowns that think they can judge me, yet cannot even read my timesheet.

So... if the company wants you gone, they will make sure you know. But you may want to consider your options if you think the company has not correctly evaluated you, because that says a lot about the competence of the company, too.

Comment: This *"So... if the company wants you gone, they will make sure you know."* is unfortunately not always true. E.g. from questions and answers I've read on this site, it appears to be fairly common for termination to follow only mildly negative feedback. It would be great if fair warning were given, but it doesn't seem to always be the case. OP will need to decide for themselves what this specific review means in their specific case unfortunately.

Comment: Many (especially large) companies have long processes for termination, and one bad review is just the first step. On the other hand, I've seen a company collect evidence for months, then dump it on the employee and fire them the same day. It depends on the company and the reason for the termination.